# Why can't localhost find bundle.js even though it is in the public directory?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, coffeescript

I'm trying to create a react app that has a server.coffee file already created for me. I set up babel and webpack and have created my index.js and app.js files. I've added script tag for bundle.js on my index.html. I keep getting error message when I run server on localhost : Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) for bundle.js:1. I see the file in my directory locally. What am I missing?

HTML File:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="/static/base.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script defer src="./bundle.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="app"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

my webpack:

```
module.exports = {
  entry: ['@babel/polyfill','./client/index.js'],
  mode: 'development',
  output: {
    path: __dirname,
    filename: './public/bundle.js'
  },
  devtool: 'source-maps',
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader'
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

my .babelrc:

```
{
  "presets": ["@babel/preset-react", "@babel/preset-env"]
}
```

My directory structure:

```
client
|-index.js
|-App.js
public
|-bundle.js
|-index.html
.babelrc
package.json
server.coffee
webpack.config.js
```

This is the script I'm running:

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "coffee server.coffee",
    "start-dev": "webpack -w & coffee server.coffee"
  }
```

Finally this is the app.get in my server.coffee file:

```
# Default public
app.get '/', (req, res) ->
  res.sendFile __dirname + '/public/index.html'
```

Again this is the error I'm getting. 
GET http://localhost:3000/bundle.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)

No compile errors or anything on the terminal. Only console errors. Any help is appreciated! I know how to do the rest of the project but it's impossible without getting React running.

Comment: The error tells you exactly what the problem is - file not found, I don't think you configure your server side code correctly for bundle.js - your html code tries to access it from ./bundle.js but in your webpack config, the path to bundle.js is under public/

Comment: yes but my index.html file is in the same folder (public) so I figured you can use a relative path. The bundle.js is in my directory on vscode but doesn't seem to be fed to the browser/ accessible

Comment: With the code you have in your server.coffee, having bundle.js inside the same folder as index.html does not automatically make bundle.js available for access through ./bundle.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `express.static()` before your `app.get()` route.

```
app.use(express.static('public'))
```

Or in Coffeescript

```
app.use express.static 'public'
```

Comment: Thanks for input but I do sorry didn't want to include full server file
```# Initialize static file
app.use '/static', express.static 'public'

# Default public route
app.get '/', (req, res) ->
  res.sendFile __dirname + '/public/index.html'
```

Comment: This only makes the ‘public’ folder public

Comment: I added it but still nothing :( 
```# Initialize static file middlware
app.use '/static', express.static 'public'

app.use express.static 'public'

# Default public route
app.get '/', (req, res) ->
  res.sendFile __dirname + '/public/index.html' ```

The weird thing is bundle.js is getting created. I just don't see it in the browser being fed up. So if I go to dev.tools. There are no script files available.

Comment: Updated answer with coffeescript

Comment: This worked! Thank you. So essentially you are saying the first line only created the folder while the added line tells it to use it? I guess just want to make sure I understand why it solved the issue. :)